# google datalab chart cell magic does not work in local jupyter notebook

Tags: google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

I want to make some nice charts like you can see [here](https://www.becomingadatascientist.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/datalab/First%20Datalab%20Project%20-%20Natality%201980-1984%20Google%20Charts.html) or [here](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/blob/04c5a9660e1dec7244720bb7c3d465e9d9d4050f/tutorials/Data/Interactive%20Charts%20with%20Google%20Charting%20APIs.ipynb).

Normal Querying via `%%bq -n data` works fine.

I installed datalab [like described](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab).

If i try to make a chart with this `%chart line -d data -f field1,field2` logic, something happens, but no plot appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not mentioned in the "Using in Jupyter" section in [the installation readme](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab#using-in-jupyter), but on another wiki page I found: [Jupyter Kernel and Notebook Extensions](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/wiki/Jupyter-Kernel-and-Notebook-Extensions)
.

It's, to install a nbextension:

```
jupyter nbextension install --py datalab.notebook --sys-prefix
```

That worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, indeed the documentation wasn't very clear. It's not updated.